A new version of (/tmp/grub.0YFD8xzJMg) of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed has been locally modified
I have already looked here, but I am worried about breaking my system again. Last time, while doing do-release-upgrade(just like right now), I kept the local copy, and a few minutes later, the kernel crashed during the update.
Image of differences:


The box is actually a diff file.  The minus sign shows what the new version will remove, and the plus sign shows what will be added.  HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 and HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET look as if they've been combined into GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE, i.e. QUIET with a timeout of 0 results in a hidden menu which is what style is referring to.  I don't see any +'s or -'s relating to kernel numbers so you should be good to either use the maintainers version or merge the changes.  Debian keeps the 2 newest kernels unless you explicitly remove the 2nd.  I don't think your previous crash was related to GRUB.

@eyoung100 Ok, thanks for clarifying that these were unimportant lines.
I think the problem that caused the crash is related to a warning it kept saying: "Warning: not using lvmetad with older version" in the minutes before the kernel crash(printed 50+ warning messages(at least) relating to this).
If it crashes again, I will post a new question about it with a screenshot of the error, but I'll see if this fixes it(unlikely because I'm pretty sure LVM and GRUB are separate things in the system, but it could fix it).

Maybe the trick shared here will let you see the relevant sections of your logs.
